# LoadImage stopped working after Windows Update

Tags: c++, winapi

The updates involved are: [KB4532938](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/help/4532938/kb4532938-cumulative-update-for-net-framework) and [KB4528760](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/help/4528760/windows-10-update-kb4528760)

This is the code:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    HMODULE hInst;
    HANDLE hImg = NULL;
    hInst = LoadLibrary(L"C:\\Users\\asd\\Desktop\\asd\\test.exe");
    hImg = LoadImageW(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCEW(5234), 2, 0, 0, 0);
    if (!hImg)
        cout << GetLastError() << endl;
    cout << hImg;

}
```

[This is the .exe containing the cursor (it's a blank ahk script)](https://ufile.io/dja6sl0a)

### Before the updates:

Output: **NOT-null** handle and error-code 1813

It works!

### After the updates:

Output: **NULL** handle and error-code 1813

It doesn't work!

The only difference is the installed updates.

### The questions are:

1. Is it a bug?
2. How is it possible that the resource exists, the name is correct, the format is correct and it fails?
3. What changed that made it break, was it a bug that made it work in the first place?
4. How can I report this to Microsoft?

Comment: Maybe Microsoft broke animated cursors. It wouldn't be the first thing an update has broken.

Comment: Also, calling `GetLastError `without having received a failure before doing so is not meaningful. If you don't get a failure result from LoadImage, you can't call GetLastError to get the reason it failed. Read the documentation for LoadImage, and actually test the return value.

Comment: I didn't test the return value because I wanted to see the output from the function, when it truly succeed gives no error-code. Anyway, It's only an example, I simply ignore the error code in case the handle is not null. I just shared that both error codes are the same to see if someone with more experience can track that to an issue with the function itself.

Comment: Read again what I wrote. You cannot call GetLastError without having received a failure first, and your code does not check to see if that's the case. The calls your code makes to GetLastError could very well be meaningless, but you have no way of knowing that because you're not checking to see if you should call it or not. Its a waste of code and time to call it without knowing first if the call is appropriate.

Comment: It's only an example, it doesn't break anything, the error-code is not meaningful in case the handle is not null. BUT the handle IS NULL so the function failed and the error-code IS meaningful. I did it this way because I wanted to share the COINCIDENCE of the error-code. so please STOOOOOOOOOOOOOOP FOCUSING ON THAT, thank you.

Comment: @Kyuuri - it seems you were depending on behavior that appeared to function as you expected despite the return codes telling you that the code wasn't working. Rather than opening multiple questions and getting frustrated in chat, consider this. Your code _never_ worked - you got an error and a pointer then pretended it did. Likely as a UAF mitigation, now you don't get a pointer then assume the code worked before. Instead, both you and the OS were ignoring the error before. The OS isn't doing so any longer, so you need to do things right rather than rely on broken behavior.

Comment: Now code is "correct". But still same behaviour, works before updates, doesn't work after updates.

Comment: I'm trying to help you understand that it's likely your code didn't work before. Instead, you saw behavior you liked and declared that "working" despite the broken code. Two bugs that temporarily cancel each other aren't "working" code. At best, they're temporarily functional.

Comment: Instead of `LoadLibrary` try `LoadLibraryEx` with the `LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE` flag.

Comment: Using: `hInst = LoadLibraryEx(L"C:\\Users\\asd\\Desktop\\asd\\test.exe", NULL, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE);` hImg is NULL and the error-code is 1813. Same behaviour as with LoadLibrary

Comment: @Kyuuri "*[my previous question] was flagged as off-topic and never got active again so I will re-do the question here*" - you should have edited the previous question to add more detail to it so it could be re-opened, instead of posting the same question again. By deleting the previous question, you also lose all of [the useful comments](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206110/discussion-on-question-by-kyuuri-loadimage-works-but-still-gives-error-1814-and) that went with it that explained why your code was broken to begin with, which you chose to ignore instead of learning from them

Comment: People, I will say it one last time, I don't even now what to change again. **the code works, it works, it works! it works, it is not broken** The problem is that as the question says **before the updates** the handle is not-null and **after the updates** it is null, so it stopped working because of the updates. The code is not wrong, I need to figure out why it stopped working. A simple "GetLastError" doesn't break the code, and I already removed it.

Comment: And remy, as I said, I edited that question like 8 hours ago and it never got opened again that's why I opened a new one. And again **the code is not broken**

Comment: If the only thing that changed is the windows updates and it worked before and not now then it sounds like a problem introduced by the updates. Try uninstalling them and see if it starts working again. If so, report it to Microsoft through the Feedback Hub. And then try to find a workaround, as the odds are it won't ever be fixed, and certainly won't be fixed quickly.

Comment: Thank you @JonathanPotter that's a helpful answer. Yes I tried uninstalling both and it worked again. I didn't know where to report that so thank you for that, I will check it.

Comment: **Moderator Note:** Comments are not for extended discussion. I've purged a number of irrelevant meta-commentary, as well as some unfriendly comments, while attempting to keep some that are relevant and on-topic. However, discussion in the comments is simply not sustainable. **If you have suggestions and/or feedback, please post it as an answer.**

Comment: But anyway, the question got solved @JonathanPotter please post this as an answer so I can mark it as solution and people with the same problem can see the answer. Thank you for the other people that tried to help, and thank you as well to the people that ignored everything and instead focused on a little detail that didn't even matter.

Comment: @Kyuuri "*the docs state that the GetLastError value should be 0 on success*" - no, the docs do not say that, either [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-loadimagew) or [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror). The docs have never said that. And VERY FEW functions actually work that way, and the ones that DO work that way are DOCUMENTED to work that way. `LoadImage()` is not one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is not easy to clear in comments, I post it as an answer.

I did tests to reproduce this problem and found that it was only related to "KB4528760 update"(you don't need uninstall both of them).

I use `EnumResourceTypes`, `EnumResourceNames` to get that the resource does exist:

name = `MAKEINTRESOURCE(5234)`, type = `RT_ANICURSOR`.

Use `FindResource` and specify the resource type to `RT_ANICURSOR` did work.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    HMODULE hInst;
    HANDLE hImg = NULL;
    hInst = LoadLibrary(L"C:\\Users\\asd\\Desktop\\asd\\test.exe");

    HRSRC hResInfo = FindResource(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(5234), RT_ANICURSOR);
    hImg = LoadResource(hInst, hResInfo);

    if (!hImg)
        cout << GetLastError() << endl;
    cout << hImg;

}
```

Comment: Any way, I will contact the relevant engineers to get  what in KB4528760 exactly affect this. Please wait patiently here. You can also submit this issue in the feedback hub app at the same time.

Comment: I submitted it on the feedback hub as well, thank you!

Comment: I have read this feedback, do you mean `FindResource`+`LoadResource` did not work for you? It did work for me with KB4528760 + test.exe you provide

Comment: I tested it again. It worked. I tested it on another computer before and the username was different so it didn't work. Now the question is: (talking about my code) was it intended to work? or it was a simple bug?. So, did the update "fix" a bug or it actually broke it?

Comment: I have submitted it internally, waiting for confirmation. This may take some time.

Comment: Thank you for that. I will check this question from time to time to see if there is any update

Comment: We have confirm this issue, and Microsoft Engineers are working on this issue.